# How to add headers and parameters for a rest service from xamarin forms c#

Tags: httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

```
User login endpoint (POST Method)
```

https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/user/login

Sample Input

cobrandName is passed as path parameter

cobSession is passed as Authorization Header

loginName and password are passed as form parameters

cobrandName = name of the cobrand

loginName=testuser

password=Yodlee123

Authorization:{cobSession=06142010_1:6666b4df326b8a26d6263054bdc4d1725d075230a082b8059ad7c20777b65d836b4eaa2dbf69169a448162c0ea09223012f130934cdee19114577f4c4a66c209}

so this is the sample data api data. i've done many posts to an api to my own server but never had to add headers.. and a little confused?

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        //httpContent.Headers.Add()
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl, httpContent);
        var RegisterResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        CobrandLoginModel TheObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CobrandLoginModel>(RegisterResponse);
```

i can make my first call and populate the the model. but then i need to send off again with the sessionid(token) but i need to insert it into a header. my sessionid returned will be the authorization id for the next postasync.

i think the correct way is this

```
            httpClientUser.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("userSession", TheObject.session.cobSession);
```

am i on the right track??

do i need to create the 
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

how do i create the format

i need to send 3 parameters
i need to add the authorization header of the returned sessionid?

thanks

EDIT

here is the url that im studying
https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Getting_Started

need to add parameters
need to add a auth header
then post

UPDATE

---

I've ended up with this

```
var httpClientUser = new HttpClient();
        var UserJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newuser);
        HttpContent httpContentUser = new StringContent(UserJson);
        httpContentUser.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var createTheToken = "cobSession=" + TheObject.session.cobSession;
        var check =  httpClientUser.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "{" + createTheToken + "}");
        var CompleteResult = await httpClientUser.PostAsync(YodleeUserLoginUrl, httpContentUser);
        var RegisterResponseUser = await CompleteResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        YodleeUserModel LoggedInUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YodleeUserModel>(RegisterResponseUser);
```

it still does not work... using the same credentails on ARC i can get the response.

but passing the values via the application does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a REST client library specifically for using Xamarin Forms. The library sits across all platforms. You can see it here or grab the NuGet. There are Xamarin Forms examples included.

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net/overview

Here is an example of how to add a header:

```
_BitbucketClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

httpClientUser.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);